# Причина постановки запятой: "Мне нужна помощь, я тут один"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, синтаксис, двоеточие, бсп

*Мне нужна помощь, я тут один.*

Почему в этом предложении мы ставим запятую перед "я"?

Comment: Потому что это бессоюзное сложное предложение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Мне нужна помощь, я тут один.***

Это бессоюзное сложное предложения (БСП), причем второе предложение указывает на **причину** первого. В этом случае ставится **двоеточие**, но при отсутствии предупредительной интонации (увеличенной паузы) допускается постановка **запятой** (обычно для **нераспространенных** предложений).

**Розенталь,** § 44. Двоеточие в бессоюзном сложном предложении

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=150#pp150

6. Если вторая часть бессоюзного сложного предложения указывает основание или причину того, о чем говорится в первой части, то между частями ставится двоеточие (между частями можно вставить причинные союзы потому что, так как, поскольку и т. п.): *Однако пора вставать: уже без четверти шесть* (П.); *Печален я: со мною друга нет* (П.);

**Примечание.** При отсутствии предупредительной интонации двоеточие в этих случаях не ставится: ***Сейчас не поедешь, жарко*** (Ч.).

Answer (score 0):

Запятую тут следует поставить, руководствуясь правилами пунктуации в бессоюзном сложном предложении (см. подробнее [здесь](https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL05/71827528.html)).

> Между предикативными частями бессоюзного сложного предложения ставится запятая, если эти части близки между собой по смыслу: *Метель не утихала, небо не прояснялось* (П.); *Бледные щёки впали, глаза сделались большие, *большие, губы горели* (Л.); День был серый, небо висело низко, сырой ветерок шевелил верхушки трав* (Т.). <...>

Однако тут можно вместо запятой поставить двоеточие (см. подробнее также [здесь](https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL05/71827528.html)).

> Двоеточие ставится между частями бессоюзного сложного предложения, если вторая часть указывает основание или причину того, о чем говорится в первой части (между обеими частями можно вставить причинные союзы *потому что*, *так как*, *поскольку* и т. п.): *Однако пора вставать: уже без четверти шесть* (П.); *Печален я: со мною друга нет* (П.); *Он покраснел: ему было стыдно убить чело века безоружного* (Л.). <...>

**ВЫВОД**

Наиболее подходящими знаками здесь будут запятая или двоеточие, что объясняется правилами пунктуации бессоюзного сложного предложения. Можете примерить:

*Мне нужна помощь, я тут один.*

*Мне нужна помощь: я тут один.*

Comment: 1. Желательно приводить ссылки из Розенталя (лучше пользоваться первоисточником, чем пересказом). 2. В ответе указано два решения, а нужно выбрать одно. 3.  Что означает фраза: по смыслу предложения близки между собой? По-моему, ничего не обозначает. Если простые предложения объединены в сложное, то они всегда в чем-то близки по смыслу. 4. Вот чем плох ПЕРЕСКАЗ "орфограммки" –  НЕТОЧНОСТЬЮ терминологии и определений. В действительности здесь именно причинно-следственные отношения, но по Розенталю автор может не обозначать их  и заменить двоеточие запятой.